# Referential Insert - Stored Procedure - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I working in .Net Application. Here in my aspx page, i am having 3 Tabs (i.e) Tab 1, Tab 2,Tab 3. The first Tab contains some Textbox controls, the Second tab contains some combo box controls and same as Third tab contains some controls. I want to save all these three tab controls to THREE different tables in SQL Database. Only one Stored Procedure should be used for this. The PRIMARY KEY of the FIRST table should be saved in the SECOND and THIRD table. ( LIKE, REFERENTIAL INSERT ). Here is my SP...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert]
(@Name NVARCHAR(50))        
 AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @TableOnePrimaryKey INT

BEGIN

INSERT INTO TABLEONE(Name)
VALUES (@Name)               

SELECT @TableOnePrimaryKey=@@IDENTITY
SELECT CAST(@@IDENTITY AS INT)

INSERT INTO TABLETWO(TableTwoIDColumn)
VALUES (@TableOnePrimaryKey) 

SELECT @TableOnePrimaryKey=@@IDENTITY
SELECT CAST(@@IDENTITY AS INT)

INSERT INTO TABLETHREE(TableThreeIDColumn)
VALUES (@TableOnePrimaryKey)               

SELECT @TableOnePrimaryKey=@@IDENTITY
SELECT CAST(@@IDENTITY AS INT)

INSERT INTO TABLEFOUR(TableFourIDColumn)
VALUES (@TableOnePrimaryKey)  

END
```

But, its the TABLE ONE Primary key is not got saved in other tables. How to Fix this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`scope_identity()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) instead of [`@@identity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx). And you should not assign the value to `@TableOnePrimaryKey` more than once. If you have an identity column in the other tables you loose the identity you got from the first insert.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert]
(@Name NVARCHAR(50))        
 AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON
  DECLARE @TableOnePrimaryKey INT

  INSERT INTO TABLEONE(Name)
  VALUES (@Name)               

  SET @TableOnePrimaryKey=SCOPE_IDENTITY()

  INSERT INTO TABLETWO(TableTwoIDColumn)
  VALUES (@TableOnePrimaryKey) 

  INSERT INTO TABLETHREE(TableThreeIDColumn)
  VALUES (@TableOnePrimaryKey)               

  INSERT INTO TABLEFOUR(TableFourIDColumn)
  VALUES (@TableOnePrimaryKey)  

END
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be using scope_identity over identity.

From http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

> "To avoid the potential problems associated with adding a trigger
>   later on, always use SCOPE_IDENTITY() to return the identity of the
>   recently added row in your T SQL Statement or Stored Procedure."

Try that and see if it fixes your issue.

**Edit:** I meant to mention that I think you need to set the variable differently. Try the following;

```
SET @TableOnePrimaryKey = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY())
SELECT CAST(@TableOnePrimaryKey AS INT)
```

etc etc